# Pandas Correction Previous Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd

#create dataframe
df= pd.DataFrame({"Date":range(0,22),
                  "Country":["USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA",],
                  "Number":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,6,4,6,7,8,7,10,25,50,75,60,45,100]
                  "Number is Corrected":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,10,25,50,50,60,60,100]})
```

But this dataframe is have a problem. Some numbers are wrong.

Previous number always has to be smaller than next number(6,*4*,6,,7,*8*,7...50,75,*60*,*45*,100)

I don't use `df.sort` because it's not about sorting it's about correction.

Edit: I added corrected numbers in "number is corrected" column.

Comment: Can you add correct Dataframe output from sample data?

Comment: Hi @jezrael. I edited.

Comment: Need `Previous number always has to be smaller than next number` - it is like change `6,4,6` to `6,6,6`, but if `7,8,7` there is problem, because `first 7` is less like `8`, so `second 7` shoud be changed to `8` (because previous 8 ia not less like 7). So it means rules are more complicated like `Previous number always has to be smaller than next number`

Comment: Same problem in last values `50,75,60,45,100` to `50,50,60,60,100`.

Comment: In another words how is possible distingush if next higher values like `8, 75` in data are not correct?

Comment: @jezrael thank you so much. It's possible also you are right. Best solution is using your cummax sugesstion

Comment: I only ask for clarification of your output.

Comment: @jezrael . I created this numbers in my mind. Actually  I expected numbers like what I wrote. This project would be use plotting data for covid 19. when I plotting countries' datas. I found some mistakes cause sometimes trends were going down but cumilative thing how can goes down? So I try to find solution as an amateur coder. And I see your solution is good

Answer (score 0):

guessing from your 'Number corrected' list, you could probably use this:

```
import pandas as pd

#create dataframe
df= pd.DataFrame({"Date":range(0,22),
                  "Country":["USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA",],
                  "Number":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,6,4,6,7,8,7,10,25,50,75,60,45,100]})
#                  "Number is Corrected":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,10,25,50,50,60,60,100]})

def correction():
    df['Number is Corrected'] = df['Number']
    cache = 0
    for num, content in enumerate(df['Number is Corrected'], start=0):
        if(df['Number is Corrected'][num] < cache):
            df['Number is Corrected'][num] = cache
        else:
            cache = df['Number is Corrected'][num]
    print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    correction()
```

but there is some inconsistency, like your conversation with jezrael. Evtl. you'll need to update the logic of the code, if it gets clearer, what the output you wished. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for help. I’ll take a look your codes when I reach my computer